# What significance level is required with a small data set?

Tags: statistical-significance, spss, small-sample

My apologies if this has been answered here. It's my first time here.

I am a developer by trade. I am not really into this thing, but I was asked to do some data simulation using SPSS. But I am not sure what significance level to use. I was given a small data set of 24 cases. This is medical research so I assume I have to use .01.

I just don't know if it is proper to change the default level of .05 in SPSS given I have only a small data set. Somebody please shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The significance level is your choice.  It doesn't depend on sample size or the type of research you are doing.  What is involved is how much risk of a type I error you wan tto take.  The type I error is the probablility that you reject the null hypothesis when you shouldn't.  The 0.01 and 0.05 levels are used only as a matter of tradition.  There is no mandatory significance level.

Answer (score 0):

What test are you using? A lot of tests have an assumption of normality somewhere that breaks down with small numbers. The significance level depends on how sure you want to be?

Comment: I am doing a two way anova.